# Filling a view that has `wrap_content` as height

Tags: android, xml

So I'm using a `RecyclerView`, with some cards. I want to get an overlay on the card when it's clicked, which should cover all contents, but not change the size of the view. Hardcoding the size of the card is not possible, since the contents have different dimensions.

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <!--contents and stuff-->

    <View
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="#000" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

The example above is pretty much what I'm trying to achieve, but this obviously won't work, since the `View`'s and `RelativeLayout`'s height refer to each other.

How can I make the `View` cover everything inside the `RelativeLayout`?

Edit
Clarification: The issue I'm having has nothing to do with clicking, covering or anything like that. I'm having issues with just covering the `RelativeLayout`.

Comment: are you toggling the View's visibility when you click a card?

Comment: did your try to use a FrameLayout instead of relative ??

Comment: @AgileNinja Not quite yet, I can't even get the view to properly cover the card, since I don't know how to tell it to fill the view.

Comment: @thunder413 I haven't, no. How would that make a difference (no experience wit FrameLayouts)?

Comment: Is the XML code you posted the depicting a card? or is it depicting the code containing the RecyclerView?

Comment: @AgileNinja That bit of code is depicting a single card.

Comment: @thunder413 is right i guess there are some issue with card layout height you have to predifine your Cardlayout's height so you need to go vanilla way here that is use a FrameLayout to display a View and set it's elevation to maybe 8dp this will give the card effect without messing up with height

Comment: FrameLayout child wil fill the parent regardless to the parent rules and is not  affected by other parent child rules

Comment: the only downsite of this method is you don't get a rounded shape corner .(I do't know  cause I haven't tried this out but maybe setting rectangle with rounded corner might help).

Comment: I'll look into FrameLayouts tomorrow

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Credits go to [thunder413](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4370476/thunder413) for suggesting the `FrameLayout` in the comments.

Basically, all I had to do was encapsulating the `RelativeLayout` (as shown in my question) in a `FrameLayout`, and move the `View` out of the `RelativeLayout` into the `FrameLayout`

```
<FrameLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <!--contents and stuff-->

    </RelativeLayout>

    <View
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="#000" />

</FrameLayout>
```